# How to append elements on infinite scroll without blocking scroll animation

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, dom-events

I have a UL that dynamically adds elements to the bottom if the user scrolls past a given threshold.
However, when the elements are being created, then appended (vanilla js style, 
i.e.:

```
container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + newHtmlString;
```

)

However, doing so makes the scrolling jumpy since, I'm assuming, modifying the DOM like that blocks scrolling animation/event triggering.

Scroll event is being attached like this:

```
//scrollableList is a jquery element
this.scrollableList.on('scroll', e => {
    /*
    function that handles checking where 
    scroll position is and appending
    */
 })
```

Is there a way to change/appendTo the HMTL so that the scrolling stays smooth?

Comment: How are you attaching your DOM scroll event? Please post sample code with a bit more context

Comment: Have you tried using [element.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/appendChild), instead of `element.innerHTML`?

Comment: @JoshuaManns edited to include listener

Answer (score 0):

You are wrestling with browser performance due to the continuous calling of the 'scroll', which is expensive. Please consider using a `debounce` function instead of your regular anonymous fn when handling browser scrolling.
[See this accepted answer for more information on debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410776/eventhandler-is-disabled-for-longer-than-expected/49411034#49411034):

Also, you should use `el.appendChild` instead of `el.innerHtml` to prevent a complete redraw of the DOM, which will save some cycles.